# How to solve factorisation and combination problem

Tags: combinatorics

20 students take a test with three questions A,B and C. 16 students answer at least one question correctly. 10 answer question A correctly, 8 answer question B correctly, 6 answer question C correctly. 3 students answer both A and B correctly, 4 answer A and C correctly and 1 student answers all three questions correctly. How many students answer questions B and C correctly?

What would be the approach to solving this problem? I am aware the answer is 2 but would like understand concepts more. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at Venn diagrams: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: ok thanks i was able to draw the venn diagram

Comment: Are you familiar with Inclusion-Exclusion principle?

Comment: No but I will research it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the venn diagram and the Inclusion-Exclusion principle. Both are the concept to solve the problem above.